# Numpy.eye() in Python 3

Tags: python, data-mining, programming

I'm using `numpy.eye(N, M, dtype=int)` to print a matrix whose diagonal elements are 1 and rest of the elements are 0. Code:

```
import numpy
import sys

line = sys.stdin.readline()

N, M = map(int, line.split())

print numpy.eye(N, M, dtype=int)
```

The above runs successfully in Python 2. But in python 3 I get the following error:

```
File "solution.py", line 7
    print numpy.eye( N , M , dtype =int )
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there an alternate package other than numpy in Python 3 through which I can accomplish this? Has the `eye` function become obsolete with Python 3?

Comment: Welcome to DataScience.SE! If your question has been resolved, please tick the answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, the `print` function has changed; it needs to be treated as a proper function, with parentheses. Try:

```
print(numpy.eye(N, M, dtype=int))
```